# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\sec(7x)\tan(7x)$

Tags: calculus

I have tried to use U-Substitution and thought about using integration by parts but can't seem to understand how the answer is $\frac{1}{7cos(7x)} + C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $\color{green}{u=\sec(7x)}.$

Then $\underbrace{\frac{du}{dx}=7\sec(7x)\tan(7x)}_{\text{Exercise-- use the chain rule.}} \iff \frac{1}{7}du=\sec(7x)\tan(7x)dx$.

Then we have

### $$\frac{1}{7}\int du =\frac{1}{7}\color{green}{u}+C=\frac{1}{7} \color{green}{\sec(7x)}+C\equiv\boxed{\frac{1}{7\cos(7x)}+C}$$

Comment: So sec(7x) is the same thing as cos^(-1)(7x)?
Edit: I guess I knew that sec is the opposite of cos but never really thought about the cos^(-1) meaning "cos in the denom"

Comment: Be careful about notation. $\cos^{-1}(x) \equiv \rm{arcos}(x)$ usually denotes the *inverse* of the cosine function; that is the angle whose cosine is $x$. $\sec(x)$ on the other hand, is equivalent to $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$.

Comment: In an ideal world, $\cos^{-1}(x)$ would be equivalent to $\frac{1}{\cos(x)},$ but in reality, $f^{-1}(x)$ denotes the inverse function of $f$, **not** its reciprocal.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, I always use $\rm{arcos}(x)$ as the inverse function of $\cos$, and $\sec(x)$ as the recpirocal of $\cos(x)$ (and avoid the notation $\cos^{-1}(x)$ altogether).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I don't have the trig functions drilled in my head yet. This problem still isn't making much sense to me though. So we make u = sec(7x) and I would assume du would be (1/7)sec(7x)du so that we could make it equal to tan(7x)dx allowing us to substitute. This would give us (u)(1/7)(sec(7x)).. which isn't the answer. How do I know to just make it (1/7)(du) and not what I was solving for?

Comment: Fundamentally, it looks like you're not understanding the fact that $\frac{d}{d\theta}[\sec(\theta)]=\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)$.

I'll prove it.

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}[\sec(\theta)]=\overbrace{\frac{d}{d\theta}[\{\cos(\theta)\}^{-1}]=-1\cdot [\cos(\theta)]^{-2} \cdot [-\sin(\theta)]}^{\text{chain rule}}\equiv\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} \equiv \frac{1}{\cos(\theta)} \cdot \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\equiv \boxed{\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)}$$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to remember that the derivative of $\sec t$ is $\sec t\tan t$.
If you happen not to remember that, one useful strategy is to convert to sines and cosines. So we are interested in
$$\int \frac{\sin(7x)}{\cos^2(7x)}\,dx.$$
Let $u=\cos(7x)$. Then $du=-7\sin(7x)\,dx$, so we want
$$\int -\frac{1}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{u^2}\,du.$$

Comment: This is what I was writing, but I see I am too late. +1